# Create a loop for calculating values from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

Let's say I make a dummy dataframe with 6 columns with 10 observations:

```
X <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20, c=21:30, d=31:40, e=41:50, f=51:60)
```

I need to create a loop that evaluates 3 columns at a time, adding the summed second and third columns and dividing this by the sum of the first column:

```
 (sum(b)+sum(c))/sum(a) ... (sum(e)+sum(f))/sum(d) ...
```

I then need to construct a final dataframe from these values. For example using the dummy dataframe above, it would look like:

```
        value
1.     7.454545
2.     2.84507
```

I imagine I need to use the *next* function to iterate within the loop, but I'm fairly lost! Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you repeat the values? eg `sum(b)+sum(c))/sum(a) ` then `sum(d)+sum(c))/sum(a)` or should it be `sum(d)+sum(c))/sum(b)`

Comment: Hi Onyambu, no the values don't repeat -- it's every 3 discrete columns. So c+b/a, then e+f/d, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` your data frame into groups of 3 by creating a vector with `rep` where each element repeats 3 times. Then with this list of sub data frames, (s)apply the function of summing the second and third columns, adding them, and dividing by the sum of the first column.

```
out_vec <- 
  sapply(
    split.default(X, rep(1:ncol(X), each = 3, length.out = ncol(X)))
    , function(x) (sum(x[2]) + sum(x[3]))/sum(x[1]))

data.frame(value = out_vec)
#      value
# 1 7.454545
# 2 2.845070
```

You could also sum all the columns up front before the sapply with `colSums`, which will be more efficient.

```
out_vec <- 
  sapply(
    split(colSums(X), rep(1:ncol(X), each = 3, length.out = ncol(X)))
    , function(x) (x[2] + x[3])/x[1])

data.frame(value = out_vec, row.names = NULL)
#      value
# 1 7.454545
# 2 2.845070
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tapply`:

```
tapply(colSums(X), gl(ncol(X)/3, 3), function(x)sum(x[-1])/x[1])
       1        2 
7.454545 2.845070
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
X %>% 
     summarise(across(.fn = sum)) %>% 
     pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
     group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n()))) %>% 
     summarise(value = sum(lead(value)/first(value), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
     select(value)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  value
#  <dbl>
#1  7.45
#2  2.85
```